# Vertical line drops out when I use a multirow

Tags: tables, multirow

I have the following table in a latex document:

```
 \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Relevant Deltares projects}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      Project Number & Description \\
      \hline
      X & \multirow{2}{*}{Multirow}\\
      X \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:relevant_projects}
  \end{table}
```

When I compile and render this however one of the vertical lines is missing:

[image]

Why does this occur? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `X \\` to `X & \\`

A compilable solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Relevant projects}
    \label{tab:relevant_projects}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      Project Number & Description \\
      \hline
      X & \multirow{2}{*}{Multirow}\\
      X & \\ % <-- note the "&" particle
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For information, I cite `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`: with that environement, the output will be as expected even with an uncomplete row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Relevant Deltares projects}
    \label{tab:relevant_projects}
    \begin{NiceTabular}{|c|c|}
      \hline
      Project Number & Description \\
      \hline
      X & \Block{2-1}{Multirow}\\
      X \\
      \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]